# Read from socket less than is available to read

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I cannot find the answer for this one: what will happen if I read from socket 4bytes (I set the limit for 4 bytes) but there are actually 256bytes awaiting to be read? Will they be lost or will they wait until the next call of read function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what kind of socket you use. If it is stream socket (created with SOCK_STREAM), then it supports a stream of data, and you can read it even by 1 byte (though it will be not efficient), on another side you may request 1024 bytes but get only 1. And that almost irrelevant by what portions sender put them into stream (there is dependency, but you should not rely on that). So with stream you need to define end of data by higher level protocol. You may send strings with \n at the end, or use zero terminated string, or send some bytes of size of coming data before that data.
On another side if you use datagram protocol (created with SOCK_DGRAM) you will get data by packets - whatever size sender sent them. If you provide smaller buffer than data available, it will be truncated and remaining data is discarded.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a TCP socket, then no data will get lost; it'll get queued up.

Bear in mind that you have to be prepared to deal with partial reads, i.e. where you get fewer bytes than requested and have to call `read()` again to get more.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However what I was concerned about was the opposite situation: reading less than is available.